# it closes rapidly as soon as it opens on running in physical device

Tags: java, android

**java**
**android**
**main activity**

here on running on physical device app closes rapidly ,can see just a flash of app opening and closing it is for adding 2 numbers
there are no errors shown ,apps runs without errors but in logcat it is shown
"Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.addingtwonumbers/com.example.addingtwonumbers.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference"

```
package com.example.twonumbersaddition;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    EditText n1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.INPUT1);
    EditText n2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.INPUT2);
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void add(View v)  //add method for adding 2 numbers
    {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText().toString());
        int j = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText().toString());
        int k= i+j;

    }
}
```

**manifest file**

the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.addingtwonumbers">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AddingTwoNumbers">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> //  activity is defined as 
            <intent-filter>//it is automatically ,have not modified it
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: thankyou sir i am new here and now facing above problem i searched  for logcat problem  "Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo" it showed that we have to declare activity in manifest file but there is no extra activity(created by me)  and manifest file code is untouched , pls help thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Move your findViewById calls to the onCreate method after you call setContentView.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    EditText n1;
    EditText n2;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        n1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.INPUT1);
        n2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.INPUT2);
    }
    public void add(View v)  //add method for adding 2 numbers
    {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText().toString());
        int j = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText().toString());
        int k= i+j;

    }
}
```

When you call findViewById before onCreate, on Activity instantiation it will try to bind your views, since the Activity component doesn't exist yet, you get some errors.